# Office Add-in to execute on save

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, office-2007, office-interop

I'm developing an Office 2007 add-in.  I would like to have a piece of code execute whenever the user Saves a document.  I'm principally interested in Word, Excel and PowerPoint, but I'd prefer to also support other Office apps (such as Visio and Microsoft Project).

Looking for either a code sample, or a link to an article that describes the basic steps to perform.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting closer.  Apparently what I want is the [DocumentBeforeSave event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb221290.aspx)

Comment: ... which can be [handled in C#][2]

2: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/088da6c4-cbef-4920-abbb-1c0424da9285/

Comment: this page explains how to hook DocumentBeforeSave for Word 2007: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx